# Best way to switch between models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I'm writing a simple page for creating an account, either as a Person or a Company.
Both models share most properties, such as username, address, etc. but with some differences.

A radio button list at the beginning will let you choose which.

**What would be the 'best' way to do this?**

Should I just create a different view/controller for each, or load partial views with ajax when selecting the radio buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's really not a "best way to do it" since models are supposed to be simple enough without encapsulating any business logic whatsoever. That said, it's really up to you to choose the approach that best suits your solution.

If you want to use the same view. I would suggest you create a model that contains the shared properties between `Persons` and `Companies` and also map any property specific to each business object. For example, is `Company` has a `CompanyID` property then map this in your model, or if `Person` has a `taxFileNumber` then map this property in your model as well

Then, in the same model add simple string property that represents the type of business object (person or company) your model is associated to. You can use this property to select the radio button list through its items' value.

If you want to use different views...well, I think it is even simpler. But, you might have more source code to maintain.